# Function inside function

Tags: javascript, function

i have no idea how to create function in function and how to use it. I created smf like this.

```js
function loadPage(nameBtn,URL,where){
$(nameBtn).click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: URL, success: function(result){
        $(where).html(result);
    }});
});
 function loadContent(where,content){
  $(where)[0].innerHTML = content;
 }
}
```

```html
<script>

loadPage("#glowna-btn","cppages/cp.glowna.php","#Container-main").loadContent("#Menu-left-bar","lololollool");

</script>
```

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish? What is wrong with the code snippet that you've posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when you write a function and expect something in return to the invocation of a function, you should first return something. In the second code block, you expect that *thing* to be an object, having method `loadContent` defined.

```js
function loadPage(nameBtn, URL, where){
    $(nameBtn).click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: URL, success: function(result){
            $(where).html(result);
        }});
    });
    
    return {
        loadContent: function(where, content){
            $(where)[0].innerHTML = content;
        }
    };
}
```

```html
<script>

loadPage("#glowna-btn", "cppages/cp.glowna.php", "#Container-main")
    .loadContent("#Menu-left-bar", "lololollool");

</script>
```

If the interface isn't important, you could simply return a function and call that (or store it in a variable, and call whenever you like).

```js
function loadPage(nameBtn, URL, where){
    $(nameBtn).click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: URL, success: function(result){
            $(where).html(result);
        }});
    });
    
    return function(where, content){
         $(where)[0].innerHTML = content;
    };
}
```

```html
<script>
    loadPage("#glowna-btn", "cppages/cp.glowna.php", "#Container-main")
            ("#Menu-left-bar","lololollool");
</script>
```